# Запись в массив-массивов-массивов файла на C

Tags: c, строки

Дан файл:

```
14;@;12;&
41;^;35;*
18;$;25;!
...
```

Нужно прочитать его в массив и потом проходить его поэлементно:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024 // хватит для всего

char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];

int main(void)
{
    char **result = NULL;
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char *tok= NULL;
    int line_nums = 4; // предположим в файле 4 строки
    fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    int linecount = 1; // первая строка с единицы
    result = malloc(line_nums * sizeof(char*)+1);
    // выделили память для указателей на 4 символа 14;@;12;&

    while ((getc(fp))!= EOF) {
      fgets(buf, BUFFER_SIZE, fp); // читаем линию
      int tokcounter = 0; // обнуляем токен-счетчик для каждой строки
      tok = strtok(buf, ";"); 
      // прочитали первое значание
      // Вопрос: здесь тоже надо как-то выделить память

      while( tok != NULL ){
        result[tokcounter] = malloc(strlen(tok) * sizeof(char *) + 1); 
        // выделяем память для элемента 
        // Вопрос: как же правильно выделить память для каждого элемента?
        strncpy(result[tokcounter], tok, sizeof(tok));
        tok = strtok( NULL, ";");
        tokcounter++;
      }
      linecount++;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    // печатаем результат

    Вопрос : почему-то теряется первая цифра: 
    //8
    //$
    //25
    //!
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       printf("%s\n", result[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { // освобождаем память
        free(result[i]);
    }
    free(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Вопросы заданы как комментарии в коде.

На выходе массив-массивов по которому можно будет пробегать построчно(как в файле) и производить действия. Т.е чтобы данные обрабатывались **построчно**, а внутри циклом по **парам**

```
while(*result != NULL ) { // цикл по строкам
    for (int k = 0; k = 4; k=k+2){ // цикл по парам 
          index //41
          index + 1 // ^ 
    } 
   ++result;    
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, приведите хотя бы ещё пару строчек в файле для примера, чтобы понять, что конкретно вам нужно "вытащить" из файла, и приведите пример матрицы, которая должна получиться.

Comment: Как-то странно Вы парсите свои строки... В примере указан как разделитель `";"` (точка с запятой), а в `strtok()` скармливаете просто запятую... Чего же Вы от него хотите? А про запись... Ну там Вы можете только копировать строки в Ваш массив (через `strncpy(), memcpy()` и т.п.). И естественно, нужно выделить всю необходимую память для `result`, а не только массив указателей.

Comment: @vladimir не копировал, набирал руками и опечатался. Как выделять память на каждой итерации цикла?

Comment: Да примерно так же, как и без цикла, только свой массив подставьте: `for(int i=0; i<=line_nums; ++i) result[i] = malloc(line_length * sizeof(char) + 1);`. (Я учел, что у Вас количество строк "+1", хотя это "+1" подразумевалось, видимо, для '\0'? - тогда оно не нужно во внешнем выделении памяти).  И в конце работы с таким массивом, освобождать нужно также сначала в цикле `result[i]`, а потом уже сам `result`.

Comment: А вот как определеить нужный размер для длины строки `line_length` - это Вы сами должны решить по требованиям задачи (по приведенному примеру, я бы подумал что и 2 (+1 на '\0') будет достаточно).

Comment: Кстати, `sizeof(result)` в цикле Вам не подходит - это даст размер указателя, а не размер массива. Используйте те размеры, что давали при выделении памяти под массив (line_nums).

Comment: Улучшил, но всё равно не совсем работает.

Comment: Подробно не смотрел, но в глаза бросилось вот это в цикле: `strncpy(result[tokcounter], tok, sizeof(tok));` - `sizeof(tok)` - даст размер указателя. Вам нужен `strlen(tok)`. И вот это: `result[tokcounter] = malloc(strlen(tok) * sizeof(char *) + 1); ` - я же написал, что здесь надо размер `sizeof(char)` (или просто 1). Теряете цифру - возможно по той причине, что для `strtok()` Вам надо к разделителям добавить еще и перевод строки `\n` (я точно не знаю - это зависит от содержимого файла, но подозреваю, что надо).

Comment: К добавке: `while(*result != NULL ) { // цикл по строкам` - сейчас это просто бесконечный цикл. Пока не предусмотрите внутри цикла изменение указателя `*result`. Но на мой взгляд, раз у Вас это массив, то тут больше подходит цикл `for` с обычным перебором всех значений индексов. Про верхний предел (`line_nums`) для него - я уже писал.

Comment: И еще поправка. С теми циклами, что вы наворотили... Ваш `result`  должен быть двумерным массивом _строк_, т.е. сама переменная должна быть типа `char ***result`. Либо нужно просто на свежую голову все пересмотреть и решить, как будет удобнее все организовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас очень много недочётов (со второго раза не можете [нормально](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128728/allocate-matrix-in-c) выделить динамическую память, не закрываете открытый файловый поток, неправильно реализовываете сам процесс чтения, выходит ошибка компилятора на строке с  `strncpy`, и ,скорее всего, именно поэтому у вас вопрос, не так ли?), и поэтому исправить **ваш** код эквивалентно тому, что я просто напишу **свой**, но ничего страшного, решим вашу задачу :)

IMO, хотелось бы получать тройной указатель, но вам нужен "массив массивов", поэтому допустим, что структуру мы хотим получить следующую :

```
{ {"14"},{"@"},{"12"},{"&"},
  {"41"},{"^"},{"35"},{"*"},
  {"18"},{"$"},{"25"},{"!"} }
```

Буду краток, потому что кода будет немало.

Директивы препроцессора, которые вне функций, перед вами :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LINE_SIZE ( 128u )

#define PARAM_COUNT_PER_LINE ( 4u )

#if ( PARAM_COUNT_PER_LINE != 2 && PARAM_COUNT_PER_LINE != 4 )
  #error Parameter count should be 2 or 4.
#endif

#define DELIMITER ";"
#define DELIMITER_SYMB ';'
#define DELIMITER_COUNT ( PARAM_COUNT_PER_LINE - 1u )

/*1 - int32_t, 2 - int64-t, other option causes error*/
#define FIRST_PARAM_TYPE_OPTION 1

/* количество символов для числовых литералов*/
/* вы не уточнили, сколько буфер должен вмещать символов для числа, поэтому по умолчанию будет int32_t */

/*Расчитывал так:*/
/*1 - на конец строки, 1 - на возможный знак минуса, остальные - количество символов в максимальном числе*/
#if ( FIRST_PARAM_TYPE_OPTION == 1 )
  #define FIRST_PARAM_TYPE int32_t
  #define FIRST_PARAM_SIZE ( 12u )  /* размер для int32_t */
#elif ( FIRST_PARAM_TYPE_OPTION == 2 )
  #define FIRST_PARAM_TYPE int64_t
  #define FIRST_PARAM_SIZE ( 22u )  /* размер для int64_t */
#else
  #error Unable to set first parameter size.
#endif

#define SECOND_PARAM_SIZE ( 2u )  /*не знаю, сколько вам нужно символов, но пусть будет один + символ конца строки*/
```

Для валидации файла я буду использовать функцию `get_lines_count`. При хоть одной "невалидной" строчке функция будет возвращать ноль, в остальных - количество прочитанных "правильных" строк.

```
static size_t get_lines_count ( const char* filename )
{
  FILE* fp;
  size_t lines_count = 0u;
  char line[ MAX_LINE_SIZE ];

  fp = fopen( filename, "r" );
  if ( NULL == fp ) return 0u;

  while ( fgets( line, MAX_LINE_SIZE, fp ) != NULL )
  {
    if ( 0 != is_valid(line) )
    {
      fclose(fp);
      return 0u;
    }
    lines_count++;
  }

  fclose(fp);
  return lines_count;
}
```

Ключевая функция здесь - `is_valid`. Именно она нужна для правильной валидации строки. Если можете улучшить реализацию - "вперёд".

```
static int is_valid( char* line ) /*скорее всего, можно и эффективней*/
{
  size_t symb_counter = 0u;
  size_t match_symb_count = 0u;
  size_t line_length;

  if ( NULL == line ) return -1;
  line_length = strlen(line);

  /*если точка с запятой в самом начале */
  if ( DELIMITER_SYMB == line[0u] ) return -2;

  while ( symb_counter < line_length )
  {
    /* если попалась точка с запятой, и за ней не идёт следующая*/
    if ( DELIMITER_SYMB == line[symb_counter] && DELIMITER_SYMB != line[symb_counter + 1u] ) 
       match_symb_count++;

    symb_counter++;
  }

  if ( DELIMITER_COUNT != match_symb_count ) return -3;
  return 0;
}
```

**Допустим**, что все строчки после этого будут валидны. Как реализовать считывание? Воспользуемся `get_params_from`, которая принмает на себя имя файла и количество строк в файле ( как вы могли догадаться,`get_lines_count` будет применяться "извне" )
Вот моя реализация :

```
char** get_params_from( const char* filename, size_t lines_count )
{
  FILE* fp;
  char** result;
  char tmp_buf[MAX_LINE_SIZE];

  size_t all_param_counter = 0u;

  if ( 0u == lines_count ) return NULL;

  fp = fopen( filename, "r" );
  if ( NULL == fp ) return NULL;

  result = ( char** ) malloc ( sizeof( char* ) * lines_count * PARAM_COUNT_PER_LINE );
  while ( all_param_counter < lines_count * PARAM_COUNT_PER_LINE )
  {
    result[all_param_counter] = ( char* ) malloc ( sizeof( char ) *  FIRST_PARAM_SIZE ); 
    result[all_param_counter + 1u] = ( char* ) malloc ( sizeof( char ) *  SECOND_PARAM_SIZE );
    all_param_counter += 2u;
  }

  all_param_counter = 0u;
  while ( fgets( tmp_buf, MAX_LINE_SIZE, fp ) != NULL || all_param_counter < lines_count * PARAM_COUNT_PER_LINE )
  {
    tmp_buf[strcspn( tmp_buf, "\n" )] = '\0'; /*один из коротких способов убрать newline из конца*/

    paramcpy( result[all_param_counter], strtok( tmp_buf , DELIMITER), FIRST_PARAM_SIZE );
    paramcpy( result[all_param_counter + 1u], strtok( NULL , DELIMITER), SECOND_PARAM_SIZE );

    #if ( PARAM_COUNT_PER_LINE == 4 )
      paramcpy( result[all_param_counter + 2u], strtok( NULL , DELIMITER), FIRST_PARAM_SIZE );
      paramcpy( result[all_param_counter + 3u], strtok( NULL , DELIMITER), SECOND_PARAM_SIZE );
    #endif

    all_param_counter += PARAM_COUNT_PER_LINE;
  }

  fclose(fp);
  return result;
}
```

### Немного комментариев к функции :

- Посмотрите на этот "кусок" :

  ```
  result = ( char** ) malloc ( sizeof( char* ) * lines_count * PARAM_COUNT_PER_LINE );
  while ( all_param_counter < lines_count * PARAM_COUNT_PER_LINE )
  {
    result[all_param_counter] = ( char* ) malloc ( sizeof( char ) *  FIRST_PARAM_SIZE ); 
    result[all_param_counter + 1u] = ( char* ) malloc ( sizeof( char ) *  SECOND_PARAM_SIZE );
    all_param_counter += 2u;
  }
  ```

  Я не знал, какой длинны (по кол-ву символов) должны быть ваши
     элементы, поэтому решил реализовать выделение динамической памяти именно так.
- Функция `paramcpy` нужна нам не только для копирования самогО
  потенциального элемента в выделенную память, но и для его валидациии.
  Реализация :

  ```
  static int paramcpy( char* parameter, char* token, size_t param_size )
  {
      if ( NULL == token || strlen(token) > param_size - 1) 
      {
        parameter[0] = '\0';
        return -1;
      }

    strncpy( parameter, token, param_size );
    return 0;
  }
  ```

  Заметьте, что при невалидности мы просто оставляем элемент пустым, но вы можете отлавливать это в `get_params_from` ( ведь `paramcpy` ещё и -1 умеет возвращать ). Опять же, скорее всего, это можно модифицировать в лучшую сторону, так что не стесняйтесь. :)

Впринципе, вот вы и получили элементы ваши. Осталось только 2 вопроса :

1. Как освободить память?
2. Как красиво отобразить-то? :)

### 1

Это <s>,слава Богу,</s> делается чуточку проще, чем выделение :

```
void free_params_buf ( char** params_buffer, size_t lines_count )
{
  size_t all_params_counter = 0u;

  while ( all_params_counter < lines_count * PARAM_COUNT_PER_LINE )
  {
    free(params_buffer[all_params_counter]);
    all_params_counter++;
  }

  free(params_buffer);
}
```

### 2

Ну можно вот так :

```
void print_params_buf( char** params_buffer , size_t lines_count )
{
  size_t lines_counter = 0u;
  if ( NULL == params_buffer || 0u == lines_count ) return;

  printf("{\n");
  while ( lines_counter < lines_count * PARAM_COUNT_PER_LINE )
  {
    printf("   {\"%s\"},{\"%s\"}", params_buffer[lines_counter], params_buffer[lines_counter + 1u] );
    #if ( PARAM_COUNT_PER_LINE == 4 )
      printf(",{\"%s\"},{\"%s\"}", params_buffer[lines_counter + 2u], params_buffer[lines_counter + 3u]);
    #endif
      puts("");
    lines_counter += PARAM_COUNT_PER_LINE;
  }
  printf("}\n");

}
```

### Остальное

- `main` использовал следующий :

  ```
    int main( void )
    {   
        char const* filename = "file.txt";
        size_t file_lines_count = get_lines_count(filename);
        char** all_params_buffer = get_params_from( filename, file_lines_count );

        print_params_buf( all_params_buffer, file_lines_count );
        free_params_buf(all_params_buffer, file_lines_count);

        return 0;
    }
  ```

  Вот поэтому `get_lines_count` я использовал "извне" : если в самих
  функциях вызывать, то многовато обращений к файлу будет :D
- Модуль <s>(с вашими вопросами полноценные модули можно делать)</s>
  умеет ещё и работать не только с форматом "%s;%s;%s;%s", но ещё и
  "%s;%s" ( поменять значение `PARAM_COUNT_PER_LINE` на `2u` ну и саму
  структуру файла, конечно :D)
- Чтобы привести к целочисленному типу каждый нечётный элемент (то есть
  ваши целочисленные), можете использовать `strtol` и привести к типу,
  который приведён в препроцессинге (`int32_t` или `int64_t`).

  Допустим, я хочу 5-ый элемент получить в int32_t (это
  платформонезависимый тип для 32-хбитного инта). Тогда я делаю
  следующее :  `FIRST_PARAM_TYPE variable = (FIRST_PARAM_TYPE)
  strtol(params_buffer[5u], NULL, 10);`

  После препроцессинга это будет всё равно, что  `int32_t variable = (
  int32_t ) strtol(params_buffer[5u], NULL, 10);` (не забудьте про `#include <stdint.h>`)

### Примеры вывода

Для вашего файла :

```
{
   {"14"},{"@"},{"12"},{"&"}
   {"41"},{"^"},{"35"},{"*"}
   {"18"},{"$"},{"25"},{"!"}
}
```

Для файла вида :

```
14;@
12;&
41;^
35;*
18;$
25;!
```

И настройке `PARAM_COUNT_PER_LINE` , равной `2u` будет :

```
{
   {"14"},{"@"}
   {"12"},{"&"}
   {"41"},{"^"}
   {"35"},{"*"}
   {"18"},{"$"}
   {"25"},{"!"}
}
```

Comment: >IMO, хотелось бы получать тройной указатель, но вам нужен "массив массивов" да тройной указатель действительно нужен - как же я ошибся...

Comment: @GarfieldCat, вы запросто можете исходить из тех данных, которые я предоставил, то есть после этого как-то подстроить "char**" под "char***", а сейчас мне переделывать код уже не хочется, ибо очень много я на это времени "убил". Однако, всё равно вам спасибо :)

Comment: @GarfieldCat именно поэтому нужно сначала разобраться в вопросе, а потом его уже задавать. Позаботьтесь о себе и других в сл. раз, и все будут довольны :) А за ошибку не вините себя : у всех бывает :)